# How to apply document to the existing template

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am trying to send an email through the API but it give me Error for all email address as "The email address for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows". Thanks in Advance

Trying to do couple of things through the API.

1. Upload manually all of our existing templates to docusing(there are around 10 templates in dpd format).
2. Create a document in our server .
3. Create an envelope through API.
4. Apply the document created to the right template in docusing. ( I am trying to do this – Code attached)
5. Send the envelop. ( I got error here)
6. Download the signed document back to the server. – (This is done.)

.

```
 public void ApplyToTemplate()
{
    //// Create the recipient information
    //recipient1
    DocuSignWeb.Recipient recipient1 = new DocuSignWeb.Recipient();
    recipient1.UserName = "Client";
    recipient1.Email = "XXXX@gmail.com";
    recipient1.Type = DocuSignWeb.RecipientTypeCode.Signer;
    recipient1.RequireIDLookup = false;
    recipient1.RequireIDLookupSpecified = true;
    recipient1.RoutingOrder = 1;
    recipient1.RoutingOrderSpecified = true;
    recipient1.RoleName = "Client";
    recipient1.ID = "1";


    DocuSignWeb.Recipient[] recipients = new DocuSignWeb.Recipient[] { recipient1 };
    // Create the template reference from a server-side template ID
    DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference templateReference = new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference();
    templateReference.Template = "XXXX";
    templateReference.TemplateLocation = DocuSignWeb.TemplateLocationCode.Server;

    //templateReference.Document = new DocuSignWeb.Document();
    //templateReference.Document.PDFBytes = ConvertWordToPdfByte(@"c:\temp\a.doc");
    // Construct the envelope information

    DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation envelopeInfo = new DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeInformation();
    envelopeInfo.AccountId = "XXXXX";
    envelopeInfo.Subject = "hello from API";
    envelopeInfo.EmailBlurb = "hello";

    // Create draft with all the template information
    DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeStatus status = _apiClient.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates(new DocuSignWeb.TemplateReference[] { templateReference }, recipients, envelopeInfo, false);

    DocuSignWeb.EnvelopeStatus sendStatus = _apiClient.SendEnvelope(status.EnvelopeID, envelopeInfo.AccountId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the raw SOAP request that you are sending out and inspect its contents, it sounds like the email address you are trying to set is getting altered and not going out in the right format.

There's a lot of tools out there that can easily capture your raw request data, such as [Microsoft's SOAP Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648814.aspx), or programs like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Try using one of those to inspect your request and see what part is incorrect